# NameError: name 'firstPart' is not defined

Tags: python, if-statement

What changes should I make to the code so that I do not get the `NameError: name 'firstPart' is not defined`.

```
burgers = ['- Hamburger', '- Cheeseburger', '- McChichen', '- Double Cheeseburger', '- Big Mac']
pizza = ['- Margareta', '- Pepperoni', '- Diablo']

def question():
    print()     #spacing for beauty

    print ('-----Our Menu-----')
    print ('[1] Burgers')
    print ('[2] Pizza')
    print ()     #spacing for beauty

    firstPart = int(input('Enter the number of the category of the food you wanna order: '))

question()

if firstPart == 1:
    print ('ok')
```

Comment: `firstPart` belongs to `question()`'s scope and it is not visible outside of the function.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous is right. Scope can be confusing at first. Also, don't space for beauty until you're a more seasoned programmer. it gets out of hand *real* quick

Answer (score 1):

You can return the value and re-use it outside function scope.

```
burgers = ['- Hamburger', '- Cheeseburger', '- McChichen', '- DoubleCheeseburger', '- Big Mac']
pizza = ['- Margareta', '- Pepperoni', '- Diablo']

def question():
    print()     #spacing for beauty

    print ('-----Our Menu-----')
    print ('[1] Burgers')
    print ('[2] Pizza')
    print ()     #spacing for beauty

    return int(input('Enter the number of the category of the food you wanna order: '))

firstPart = question()

if firstPart == 1:
    print ('ok')
```

This error occurs because the variable is only available at the function scope. The scope of firstPart is limited to the function.